# Display Duration as Time in hours and minutes "hh:mm"

Tags: powerbi, dax, duration

I am trying to calculate average loading time. My data source is a SharePoint list, and so i have the time converted to text in a calculated SharePoint column. In PowerBI I then changed this column into duration where I get the displayed hours and minutes. What I cant figure out is how to set this so that I can get an average per truck. Any suggestions?

I haven't found anything yet that solves this in a thread, hoping someone can help.

Comment: If you're planning to come back to StackOverflow you'll have to learn [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In DAX the Duration is given in (fraction of) days. You can simply AVERAGE() these numbers. But if you want to show the result in Time, you have to format it accordingly:

```
Average Loading Time = 
FORMAT(
    AVERAGE('Table'[Loading Time]),
    "hh:nn"
)
```

[image]